# Create a vector layer from a raster layer contour

Tags: qgis, vector

I am using QGIS 2.18.
I have several sheets (about 430 MrSid raster files) that represents a full map. Each sheet is already geo-referenced.

I need to create a vector layer that represents the contour of each sheet.

For instance:

[image]

For this image I need to automatically create a square vector layer (polygon) that represents the 4 sides of the sheet.

Is there any way I can do it without having to manually set the coordinate of each point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the tile index in the gdal toolbox (gdaltindex).